# How to order a dictionary without using _collections or other library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

So I'm supposed to make a dictionary get ordered, and the way I'm doing it now is not valid;

```
dictionary = _collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items()))
```

because it uses the library "_collections", is there any compact way to do this without an imported library?

Comment: How about just `sorted(dictionary.items())`?

Comment: That makes a tuple pair, but I can make do with it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't. If you want ordering you'll have to resort to using `OrderedDict`; that is the only means to retain order in a dict-like object for Python `<= 3.5`.

From Python `3.6`, dictionaries remember the order of insertion by default (See: [Dictionaries are ordered in Python 3.6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/dictionaries-are-implemented-as-ordered-in-cpython-3-6/39980744#39980744)) so, you'll be able to feed a sorted sequence to it and get the ordering without use of any other modules (e.g `OrderedDict`). *Despite this*, it is best to wrap it in an `OrderedDict`; the ordering behavior of `dict`s in `3.6` *is considered an implementation detail that you should **not** depend on*.

Comment: So basically, the only clunky way to do it is to make a list of the keys first and... Magic? Ugh, this is pretty annoying.

Comment: @Grak but that's how dictionaries are implemented. If you require order why not hold them, as John suggested, in an ordered sequence like a list?